# IIS - remove and add binding

Tags: iis

I am looking at PowerShell script to do the following on IIS

add web binding https to the website and assign the only available existing cert from the certificate store

Answer (score 0):

In powershell, before binding, you need to obtain the certificate and site information, and then use this to bind site to https.

```
PS IIS:\SslBindings> get-item cert:\LocalMachine\MY\7ABF581E134280162AFFFC81E62011787B3B19B5 | new-item 0.0.0.0!443
```

This is the most important step. For more detailed steps, please refer to this [document.](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-configuring-ssl-with-the-iis-powershell-snap-in)